# High-gain feedback amplifier design using ADA4004

Tags: amplifier, analog, gain

I am trying to design a feedback amplifier with ADA4004. My desired gain is about 42dB@2kHz. Is it possible to design a stable amplifier with such gain using ADA4004?

The ADA4004`s GBP is 12MHz. The slew rate is 2.7V/us. The output voltage range is -2V~2V.
Here is the schematic:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4TOPa.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I have simulated it in Multisim and found that the phase margin is larger than 90 degree. Is it OK?

Comment: Positive feedback?

Comment: oh,sorry,not positive feedback.

Comment: A phase margin of such an amplifier cannot be above 90 deg. How did you simulate? According to the gain-phase diagram as shown below, the margin for unity gain application (worst case) is about 65 deg.

Comment: It still says "positive" in the title of the question.

Comment: Maybe I made a mistake. I learned that the phase margin is the difference between the 0dB point phase and -180 degree phase. I simulated the design and found that the 0dB point phase is about -83 degree. Then the phase margin is about 97 degree. Does this criterion correct?

Comment: You have mentioned correctly the 0dB point and the corresponding phase - however, you didn´t say which FUNCTION you are referring to. In this respect it is important to know that this criterion does apply to the LOPP GAIN only and not to the closed-loop gain.

Answer (score 1):

The open loop response of the device is this: -

[image]

In red I've drawn your actual response which has a 3dB point at about 7.4kHz and then rolls off due to the 33pF cap at 20 dB per decade of frequency.

Where the red line crosses the 0dB line on the Y axis, you can see that the phase response has hardly shifted from 90 degrees (maybe it's 85 degrees). This, to me indicates that your phase margin is about 85 degrees and should be totally stable.

Comment: Really? Thank you very much! But one problem. I am the newbie. I have not seen your way to solve the problem before. Is it a common way by drawing the closed loop gain on this kind of figure and check the 0dB phase. And that phase means the phase margin?

Comment: No - not really. For phase margin determination you need the gain and phase plot of the LOOP GAIN. That is the product of the opamps open-loop response multiplied with the ransfer function of the feedback path.

Comment: @LvW When feedback is applied and the frequency is low, the closed loop gain and phase responses become fully defined by the feedback elements. As frequency rises there comes a point where closed loop gain starts to follow the open loop gain and the same happens for phase - this won't reach this point because of the 33pF capacitor.

Comment: @Andy aka: I was of the opinion that we speak about phase margin determination, don´t we? And for this purpose, we have to investigate the HIGH fequency region where the loop gain approaches 0 db. Or did I misunderstand something?

Comment: Thank you LvW. But do you mean that I should check the bode plot of the closed loop gain after simulation and find the 0dB point to get the phase margin?

Comment: No - the stability criterionapplies to the LOOP GAIN only (series connection of opamp and feedback path in an open-loop condition).

Comment: @Andy aka: Sorry, but the red line contains no information about the phase margin. More than that, it gives not the actual closed-loop gain, which must flatten out at app. 1 MHz and stays at 0 dB (full feedback due to the cap). Because the loop gain will be zero dB slightly above 10 MHz (because of full feedback in this region) the phase margin of the amplifier is app. 55deg.

Comment: @LvW The feedback network of C1, R4 and R3 means that at LF the phase shift from output to -Vin starts about 0 degrees and rises to about ~35 degrees (at ~7.4kHz) then falls back to about 0 degrees again at HF. I think you are saying the phase margin is 55 degrees at 7.4kHz?

Comment: No - of course not. The phase margin always is determined at the frequency where the LOOP GAIN is 0 dB. In the BODE diagram, that is the frequency where the Aol response (opamps open-loop gain) meets the 1/beta response (beta: feedback function). In the above example, this is app. at a frequency of 10MHz (Aol app. 0 dB and beta=1).I just have discovered that in the diagram the (worst case) margin is given with 52.9 deg. This is also the approximate margin for our case because at 10 MHz the capacitor is roughly a short.

Comment: @LvW Interesting - seems I need to brush up on this a bit more. I'll probably do that on Monday. Do you think I should delete my answer - maybe you ought to do a proper answer and I'll delete mine. Let me know dude.

Comment: @user40109: Now I can give you a more accurate value for the margin. Because I have not the model of the opamp I have simulated the feedback function beta(s) separately. Because |1/beta| meets the Aol curve at 10MHz the phase of (1/beta) at this frequency is app. -5 deg. Hence, the loop phase is shifted beyond the -52.9 deg (given for the opamp alone). That means, we have  a reduced phase margin of (52.9-5)=47.9 deg. For such a stability margin the circuit is still stable - however, the step response will show a cerain overshoot wth a decaing ringing.

Comment: @Andy aka: I think, it would be perfect if you could display the 1/beta response (magnitude) instead of the red line. This would be fully sufficient to see the frequency where both functions meet each other and - important for the phase margin - the net slope (angle) between both curves. It will be app. 20dB/Dec (1/beta with slope =dB/dec). According to theory the margin, in this case, is 45 deg.

Comment: @LvW OK I think I'll do that but to help me brush up do you have a good site link I can use - can't do it till Monday but i can digest today!!!

Comment: @Andy aka: We need to check the point Loop gain LG=1. Because of LG=Aol*beta=1 is eqivalent to Aol=1/beta we have to find the crossing point where both responses meet. Thus, simply draw 1/beta=1+[(R4||C1)/R3]. This is sufficient to approximate the stability and the corresponding margin (rate of closure app 20dB/dec)